# Definite Integral with a variable in one of the bounds

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

So I was trying to help a friend study for his Calculus 1 test last night and I stumbled across a problem that I could not recall how to solve.

The question was: Let $f(x)=\sqrt{(t^2 + 5)}$

Find $\int_{3}^{x^3} f(t)dt$ and find $f'(x)$.
I thought I used the second half of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to solve this but that did not produce the correct result.

My Work

$F(x)=(1/3)t^3 + 5t$

$$F(x^3) - F(3)=$$
  $$ ((1/3)(x^3)^3 + 5(x^3) - ((1/3)(3)^3 + (5)3)$$
  $$((x^6)/27 + 5x^3) - 24$$
   $f'(x)=((x^6)/27 + 5x^3) - 24$

Is this correct?

Comment: Your first intuition was correct:  Use the fundamental theorem.

Comment: Your $F(x)$ is wrong, it forgot about the square root sign. In this case, we could with some pain actually integrate. But it would be a very painful way of solving the problem. Use instead the Fundamental Theorem.

Comment: I think you mean to have $ \ F'(x) \ , $ rather than $ \ f'(x) \ , $ which is something you can easily find...

Comment: The derivative of the integral comes from the fairly familiar Newton-Leibniz rule. But, the integral itself can be approximated by a power series. I do not have a definite answer yet about the exact value.

Comment: @Andre Nichols Sorry forgetting the sqrt was a typo.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner The question on his study guide said given the integral of f(x) find f'(x). Maybe they made a typo on his study guide. I havn't actively done calculus for almost 3 years now so I wouldn't have been able to spot a typo on their part.

Comment: I'd say that was pretty definitely a typo, since it otherwise makes the business with the integral one big distraction.  I'll mention that this sort of "Leibniz rule" differentiation problem is a rather "popular" exam question (popular with _examiners_, that is...)

Comment: I should also mention that  your first equation should read $ \ f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 5} \ $ ; it will become $ \ \sqrt{t^2 + 5} \ $ in the integral, where the "dummy variable" $ \ t \ $ is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually try to make the integration; instead, you apply the Chain Rule in a situation like this:

$$ F'(x) \ = \ \frac{d}{dx}  [ \ F(x^3) - F(3) \ ] \ =  \ \frac{d}{dx}  [ \ F(x^3) \ ] \ - \ 0 \ = \  \frac{d}{du} [ \ F(u) \ ] \ \cdot \frac{du}{dx}  , $$

with $ \ u = x^3 \ . $  Now, the first factor is interpreted as  $$ \frac{d}{du} [ \ F(u) \ ] \ = \frac{d}{dx} [ \ F(x) \ ] \ \vert_{u(x)} \ = \ f(x) \ \vert_{u(x)} \ = \ f(u(x)) \ ,   $$

which for this problem gives us

$$ F'(x) \ = \ f(x^3) \ \cdot \ (3x^2) \ = \ 3x^2  \cdot \sqrt{x^6 + 5 } \ . $$

(Note that the lower limit on the integral, '3' in this case, doesn't enter into the result at all...)